# Why does Worms Reloaded crash when I try to run it on Windows 7 64 Bit?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, worms-reloaded

I am having problems running Worms Reloaded on Windows 7 64 Bit. I ran the app from Steam. It displays the Team17 logo and then crashes. Why might this be happening?

Crash details:

> Faulting application name:
>   WormsReloaded.exe, version: 1.0.0.447,
>   time stamp: 0x4c727c56 Faulting module
>   name: WormsReloaded.exe, version:
>   1.0.0.447, time stamp: 0x4c727c56 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault
>   offset: 0x00216c17 Faulting process
>   id: 0x2b98 Faulting application start
>   time: 0x01cb45a40dbcaf66 Faulting
>   application path: c:\program files
>   (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\worms
>   reloaded\WormsReloaded.exe Faulting
>   module path: c:\program files
>   (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\worms
>   reloaded\WormsReloaded.exe Report Id:
>   b04c443a-b197-11df-a61f-0024e8f19bf1

Comment: Likewise. I am having the exact same problem. Might have to hit up the T17 forums on this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread on the steam forums for Vista x64 issues, so this may apply to you. These are the possible solutions they came up with:

- If you have a soundblaster card then disable it and try and run sound either through another soundcard or motherboard integrated sound.
- Create a new file in the worms folder named Local.cfg . Create this file within notepad and then just save it as that name. The file should just contain the following "/nosound".
- Verify the game cache, there may have been an issue with your download. Doing this will check for errors and redownload any files that are corrupt or missing.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1412861)

Comment: It ended up being the game cache.  once verified it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is part of an email from Team17 about some of the common things to try.

> Meanwhile, here are a few solutions to
>   the most frequent issues.
>
> - If you are having problems getting the game to launch or you are
>     experiencing random crashes, it might
>     be that the game did not install
>     correctly. Please use Steam’s
>     validation check at least twice
>     because sometimes it can report no
>     problems on its first pass.  Verify
>     integrity of game cache
>
>   - Load Steam
>   - From the Library section, right-click on the game and select
>       Properties from the menu.
>   - Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game
>       cache... button.
>   - Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several
>       minutes.
>   - Once the process is completed, the Check Window will automatically
>       exit.
>   - Another reason that your game may be crashing is that you don’t have all
>       the latest directx and video drivers,
>       please check Steam’s support page
>       here: -
>       https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1093-TEMX-7665
> - If you are experiencing sound issues with the game, please try
>     updating your sound drivers. Most
>     people after trying this have reported
>     that it works: -
>     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&DisplayLang=en
>
> Please also check the sticky threads
>   on the Worms Reloaded steam forum for
>   the latest news on bug fixes and
>   solutions: -
>   http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=941
>
> If after doing these things, your
>   problem is fixed, then please let us
>   know. If your problem still persists
>   then please send us your dxdiag file
>   and the game log file and we will find
>   out why you are still experiencing
>   problems. If you used the default
>   install, you can find the log file
>   here: -  C:\Program
>   Files\Steam\steamapps\common\worms
>   reloaded